# How to deploy files into a server that is behind NAT in CircleCI

Tags: deployment, circleci-2.0

I have a server that is behind NAT and primarily serves websites. To expose it to the internet, I utilize a low-resource VPS with an Apache reverse HTTP proxy and Tailscale. However, the setup only allows HTTP access.

Recently, I started exploring continuous integration and want to upload the build files generated by CircleCI to my server behind NAT. Typically, on a regular Linux server, I would install Tailscale and use the following command to upload the files via SSH (assuming SSH key configuration is in place):

`scp -r build-files $server-name@$tailscale-server-ip:/home/server/Code/project1`

Unfortunately, I cannot install Tailscale inside a CircleCI Docker container as it lacks a network interface.

I attempted to use the `threecomma/circleci-tailscale@2.2.0` orb, but it appears to only support HTTP and SOCKS5 protocols. I am unsure if it can help me execute the aforementioned command.

How can I upload the generated build files from the CircleCI Docker container to my server behind NAT? I am open to alternative solutions as well.

Here is my last attempt:

```yml
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:18.16.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: "Install & run tailscale"
          command: |
            curl -fsSL https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/ubuntu/focal.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
            curl -fsSL https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/ubuntu/focal.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tailscale.list
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install tailscale
            sudo tailscale up --auth-key $TAILSCALE_AUTHKEY
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: npm install
            npx expo install react-dom@18.2.0
            npx expo install expo-localization@14.1.1
            npx expo install react-native-web@~0.18.10 @expo/webpack-config@^18.0.1
      - run:
          name: Build app
          command: npm run build-web
      - run:
          name: Upload build-web folder to server behind nat
          command: |
            echo "The server ip is: $SERVER_IP"
            ssh $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP 'mkdir -p /home/server/Code/project1'
            scp -r web-build $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP:/home/server/Code/project1

workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - build:
          context: ss
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
```

Comment: To achieve this, you'll need a VPS with a public IP. Connect the VPS and your server behind NAT using Tailscale. Set up an HTTP server on the VPS to listen for POST requests containing files and paths. Save them on the VPS and then upload them to the server behind NAT via SSH using the ```scp``` command. Then create a script that uploads the folder you want though an HTTP post request. As you can see, it only works if you have a VPS with public IP, I didn't find another way.